# What is the purpose of @InitBinder's value element?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I would like to understand the @InitBinder.
I tried to use multiple InitBinder for more than one Validator

```
@InitBinder("Validator1")
protected void initBinder1(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(userFormValidator);
}

@InitBinder("Validator2")
protected void initBinder2(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(costcenterFormValidator);
}
```

it do not work for me, because the model is meanwhile nested in a wrapper class and I'll do the same for validation

so when is the @InitBinder with value an good idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/InitBinder.html), The value in @InitBinder is the names of command/form attributes and/or request parameters that this init-binder method is supposed to apply to. Default is to apply to all command/form attributes and all request parameters processed by the annotated handler class. Specifying model attribute names or request parameter names here restricts the init-binder method to those specific attributes/parameters, with different init-binder methods typically applying to different groups of attributes or parameters.

In your case, You need to set the value of the @InitBinder annotation to the name of the model attribute that you want it to validate not some name of validator. For userFormValidator, if your model attribute name is **user**, then the initbinder should be:

```
@InitBinder("user")
protected void initBinder1(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(userFormValidator);
}
```

And if costcenterFormValidator is for validating model attribute named **costcenter** then the initbinder should be:

```
@InitBinder("costcenter")
protected void initBinder2(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(costcenterFormValidator);
}
```

Comment: Can I apply init binder to a particular method and model object related to that controller only? how can I do that?

Comment: Following is my code                                                                    @InitBinder("saveCustomerProfile")
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {          binder.setDisallowedFields(new String[]{"cbr1","customerFirstName"});
}                                                                                                                   This code not setting BindingResult  result.getSuppressedFields(), and not working for the method "saveCustomerProfile".If I remove the value for init binder it is working but for whole controller..what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

```
// For multiple validations use annotations in the initBinder and give proper name of the ModelAttribute in the initBinder.

@Controller
public class Controller {
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Controller.class);

@InitBinder("ModelattributeName1")
private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(validator);

}

@Autowired
MessageSource messageSource;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("FormValidatorID1")
private Validator validator1;


@InitBinder("ModelattributeName2")
private void initBinder1(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(validator2); 
}

@Autowired
@Qualifier("FormValidatorID2")
private Validator validator2;


@RequestMapping(value = "/submit_form1", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleGetSubmission1(@Validated  @ModelAttribute("ModelattributeName1") GetFormModel1 getFormModel1,
        BindingResult result, Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("getFormModel1", getFormModel1);
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "get_Form1";
    }

    return "get_Complete1";
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/submit_form2", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleGetJavaAppletSubmission(@Validated @ModelAttribute("ModelattributeName2") GetFormModel2 getFormModel2,
        BindingResult result, Model model) {

    System.out.println(result);
    model.addAttribute("getFormModel2", getFormModel2);

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "get_Form2";
    }

    return "get_Complete2";
}
}
```